# Xamarin Forms Unfocused Event Not Firing on User Control

Tags: xamarin.forms, user-controls

I created a simple Xamarin Forms user control based on a ContentView. Since the ContentView is (ultimately) a VisualElement, I assumed the built-in Unfocused event would work as expected. However, while I can subscribe to my user control's Unfocused event, the event never fires. (Same with the FocusChangeRequested event, as it turns out.) The Xamarin documentation for the Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Unfocused event is cryptic:

`This event is not bubbled through the Forms stack and is received directly from the native control.`

How can I implement an Unfocused event within a Xamarin Forms user control? Is there something within the Xamarin Forms environment that I can intercept when the user control loses focus or, alternatively, when another control receives focus that will allow me to fire an Unfocused event?